# Change a TextView in a item of a ListView with a Button

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView im my project. Each row have 1 Button and 1 TextView with the text "free line". How can I change the text of TextView to "Occupied Line" when I click in the Button?
Now, when I click on Button the text changed is the last of my ListView.
I need to use a GetTag? But, what is a Tag?
Anybody have a simple exemple?

My Adapter:

```html
public class AdaptadorLista extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Jogo> itens;
    private View viewSelecionada;
    private int golsMandante=0;
    private int golsVisitante=0;
    private int gols=0;
    private boolean btMaisPressionado = false;
    private boolean btMenosPressionado = false;
    private ItemSuporte itemSuporte;
    private int posicaoNaLista;

    public AdaptadorLista(Context context, List<Jogo> itens) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.itens = itens;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itens.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itens.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(view == null){
            itemSuporte = new ItemSuporte();
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista, null);
            itemSuporte.btMaisGolsMandante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMaisGolsMandante));

            itemSuporte.btMaisGolsVisitante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante));

            itemSuporte.btMenosGolsMandante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMenosGolsMandante));

            itemSuporte.btMenosGolsVisitante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante));

            itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarMandante));
            itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarVistante));
            itemSuporte.txtNomeMandante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSimboloMandante));
            itemSuporte.txtNomeVisitante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSimboloVisitante));
            itemSuporte.txtDataJogo=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDataJogo));
            itemSuporte.txtLocalJogo=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLocalJogo));
            itemSuporte.simboloMandante=((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMandante));
            itemSuporte.simboloVisitante=((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgVisitante));
            view.setTag(itemSuporte);

        } else {
            itemSuporte= (ItemSuporte)view.getTag();
        }

        Jogo jogo = itens.get(position);
        itemSuporte.simboloMandante.setImageResource(jogo.getTimeMandante().getCodigoImagemSimbolo());
        itemSuporte.simboloVisitante.setImageResource(jogo.getTimeVisitante().getCodigoImagemSimbolo());
        itemSuporte.txtNomeMandante.setText(jogo.getTimeMandante().getSigla());
        itemSuporte.txtNomeVisitante.setText(jogo.getTimeVisitante().getSigla());
        itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(Integer.toString(jogo.getGolsMandante()));
        itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(Integer.toString(jogo.getGolsVisitante()));
        itemSuporte.txtDataJogo.setText(jogo.getData());
        itemSuporte.txtLocalJogo.setText(jogo.getLocal());

        itemSuporte.btMaisGolsMandante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMaisPressionado=true;
                    new AumentaGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMaisPressionado = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        itemSuporte.btMenosGolsMandante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMenosPressionado = true;
                    new DiminuiGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMenosPressionado = false;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });


        itemSuporte.btMaisGolsVisitante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMaisPressionado = true;
                    new AumentaGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMaisPressionado = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        itemSuporte.btMenosGolsVisitante.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewSelecionada = v;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    btMenosPressionado=true;
                    new DiminuiGols().execute();
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    btMenosPressionado = false;

                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        return view;
    }

    public void setGols(){
        switch (viewSelecionada.getId()) {
            case R.id.btMaisGolsMandante:
            gols = golsMandante;            
            break;

            case R.id.btMenosGolsMandante:
            gols = golsMandante;
            break;

            default:
            gols = golsVisitante;
            break;
        }
    }

    private class ItemSuporte {
        ImageView simboloMandante;
        ImageView simboloVisitante;
        TextView txtPlacarMandante;
        TextView txtPlacarVisitante;
        TextView txtNomeMandante;
        TextView txtNomeVisitante;
        TextView txtDataJogo;
        TextView txtLocalJogo;
        ImageButton btMaisGolsMandante;
        ImageButton btMaisGolsVisitante;
        ImageButton btMenosGolsMandante;
        ImageButton btMenosGolsVisitante;

    }

    class AumentaGols extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while (btMaisPressionado) {
                setGols();
                if(gols<9){
                    gols++;
                    publishProgress(gols);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId()== R.id.btMaisGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId()== R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsVisitante=gols;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMaisGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsVisitante=gols;
            }
        }

    }

    class DiminuiGols extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (btMenosPressionado) {
                if(gols>0){
                    gols--;
                    publishProgress(gols);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsMandante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsMandante=gols;
            }
            if(viewSelecionada.getId() == R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante){
                itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(String.valueOf(gols));
                golsVisitante=gols;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please post a sample of your buggy code in order to identify the problem.

Comment: you probably need to use `setOnClickListener` on a `Button` inside the getView() method of your adapter, but you need to post your code first.

Comment: please post your listView adapter code

Comment: The solution is here:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40116/manipulando-bot%C3%B5es-nos-itens-de-uma-lista

Answer (score 0):

in your listView adapter (*getView* method):

```
youButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            yourTextView.setText("Occupied Line");
        } 
    });
```

Comment: I Included my adapter code, but this is a so much complicated, because don't is the same of my question.

Comment: the Button and TextView in your question, what's their name in your adapter?

Comment: I put theirs in a item support called "itemSuporte"

Comment: in "else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    btMaisPressionado = false;
/* SET HERE YOUR TEXT*/
    }"
for each button!!